# Garlic.js on dynamically generated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I get [garlic.js](http://garlicjs.org/) to work on fields generated dynamically with Javascript, for instance like in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast) or by using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)? I have tried explicitly including the js file in the nested fields partial, but no luck:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'garlic'
.nested-fields
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :client_id #etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I got around this was using the jquery storage api: https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API to persist the HTML of the dynamically generated form in addition to invoking garlic to save the form state.

Upon page load, I check if the persisted form exists in localstorage. If it does, then load the html into the form element, then call garlic to restore form state!

Comment: I guess you must then call each and every function that might have acted on your original form prior to persistence. Eg datepicker, select2/chosen, tootip, etc, etc. Or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to explicitly call Garlic for these dynamic fields, once loaded in DOM?

```
$( '#yourloadeddiv' ).garlic();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is whenever you reload or restart your browser, the `get` request for `edit/new` is served to the server and hence the fields those are static in the respective view file are loaded with the data and the fields those were added dynamically will be lost. Hence the data will always be lost. I am not sure if the **garglic.js** will add the data to the fields those were not in the DOM on page load.