# Can I store a jQuery DOM clone in local storage for later use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, deserialization, clone

I would like to store a jQuery object representing a DOM element, for later use. Already I have these methods that carry out storage and retrieval of objects and text, to and from localStorage:

```
 var Data = {
  set: function(key, value, session) {
    if (!key) {return;}

    if (typeof value === "object") {
      value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    if(session){
        sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
  },
  get: function(key, session) {
    if(session){
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    }else{
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    }

    if (!value) {return;}

    // assume it is an object that has been stringified
    if (value[0] === "{" || value[0] === "[") {
      value = JSON.parse(value);
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

It is based, thankfully, on a Stack Overflow source, and works well for simple objects, apart from strings.

What I'm thinking about is to do this:

```
$clone = $('#myform').clone(true);
Data.set('clonedata', $clone);
```

And then, much later, elsewhere:

```
$retrieved = Data.get('clonedata');
```

Problem is, it doesn't seem to be working in this case. Is there a fundamental reason why a jQuery object cannot be serialized and deserialized in this manner?

How can this can be useful? One case is for persisting (autosaving) form data in localStorage as the user fills a long form. Then the information can be offered back after, say a network outage or inadvertent browser navigation or closure.

Comment: You should convert this to raw html and then store it.

Comment: Hmmm. But then, I'd lose all previously bound events, right?

Comment: You cannot really do this. You'd have better to tell why would you need that behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff: To implement form autosave is not a good enough reason? Is there a better method?

Comment: Then store serialized form and render it on load. I'll post an answer

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. But if there were dynamically added child elements, those will disappear on load. That's the only problem forcing me in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can use garlic.js for local persisting. hopefully this link may help you out.simple use, just include the js file and add `data-persist="garlic"` as a form attribute.it can save your form data even if your machine power failure.you can download the js file from here.

http://garlicjs.org/

Comment: I was trying to implement customized solution but i guess this would be better to just use an already done solution

Comment: @Ataur: Thanks for suggesting garlic.js. One question though: can it correctly reload, say, a field that was dynamically added after DOM load? Again, could it possibly play well with a `select2` `select`?

Comment: @A.Wolff, How I wish you didn't give up the quest so soon! I was full of expectation.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo I guess once some new element added, recall `$('#myform').garlic();`. Maybe you'd need to destroy plugin before reinitialize it, not sure how it is handled internally. `could it possibly play well with a select2` It should but for sure you need some testing

Comment: Weeks ago, I'd seen sisyphus.js. It boasts of similar features to this one. I did quite a bit of testing. Wasn't bad, but regarding added elements, it was only an item on the to-do list. (See, the problem is: when the user reopens a closed browser, the DOM structure would not be the same, so the retrieved data would find no matching inputs to bind to. That's what inspired my wanting to store ALSO the DOM structure)

Comment: plz, visit the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603227/garlic-js-on-dynamically-generated-fields

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo I forgot but you should store form markup in localstorage: `localStorage.setItem('formMarkup', $('#myform').html());` each time you add new element. Then to retrieve it: `if(localStorage.getItem('formMarkup'))
$('#myform').html(flocalStorage.getItem('formMarkup'));`

Comment: garlic.js save the form element using localStorage which is html5 feature. whatever you did, is already implemented internally in garlic.js @A. Wolff

Comment: i am not sure about dynamic elements.previous link can help you to sort out your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603227/garlic-js-on-dynamically-generated-fields @A.Wolff

Comment: Taking a look at @AtaurRahmanMunna's link, I'm justified to say that garlic.js DOES NOT persist dynamic elements. The answer by "superkelvint" bears this out. And, note that his approach is generally along same line as A. Wolff is trying to lead here. But again, please take note of my comment on that answer. Previously bound events would have to be called again, and this can then get really clumsy.